# Thread interference with methods in the same class

Tags: multithreading

For example I have a class with methods that will be used by different threads. 
The question is, will threads interfere with each other if used like this:

```
Class sharedMethods{
     void method1(){}
     static void method2(){}
}

Thread1{
     sharedMethods sm = new sharedMethods();
     while(1){
         sm.method1();
     }
}

Thread2{
     while(1){
         sharedMethods.method2();
     }
}
```

Or in this situation, when threads share same object:

```
    Class sharedMethods{
         string aa = "AAAAAAA";
         string bb = "BBBBBBB";
         string method1(){return aa;}
         string method2(){return bb;}
    }

   Class Main{
         static sharedMethods sm = new sharedMethods();
   }

    Thread1{
         while(1){
             string aa = Main.sm.method1();
         }
    }

    Thread2{
         while(1){
             string bb = Main.sm.method2();
         }
    }
```

Comment: deadlock or thread will have to wait for another to finish

Comment: then no. threads scheduling is mostly out of your hands. Mandatory waits will occur in cases of `synchronized` blocks only.

Answer (score 0):

Methods do not "interfere" with each other unless there is some state involved - class fields (variables) upon which those methods act.

In your example both method are "pure", they have no side effects (i.e. they don't change value of any variables), so both are thread safe.